# How can I disable a field in source mapping in MapStruct?

Tags: java, mapstruct

For example, I have mapping class with a field, that not presented in mapped class.

A class, **which** I want to map:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_connection")
@Getter @Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class ConnectionEntity {
    @NotNull
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected UUID id;
...
}
```

A class, **in which** I want to map:

```
@ApiModel
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ConnectionDto {
    @ApiModelProperty
    private LocalDateTime createAt;
...
// Other fields without id field
}
```

My mapper looks like this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
        unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR,
        unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)
public interface CallMapper {

    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "map")
    List<ConnectionDto> map(List<ConnectionEntity> connectionEntities);

    ConnectionDto map(ConnectionEntity connectionEntity);
}
```

I want to know, when a specific field is not been mapped, so disabling `unmappedSourcePolicy` is not a option. Any advice?

Comment: It seems it is not possible, there is one rather stupid way just to write `map()` by hand.
`default  ConnectionDto map(ConnectionEntity connectionEntity) {  
        ConnectionDto dto = new ConnectionDto();  
        dto.set ... (connectionEntity.get... );  
        return dto;  
}`

Comment: It is possible. Thanks to @sjaak. See that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54875713/11112760

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you.. You want to control the source properties you don't want to map?

In that case try:

`@BeanMapping#ignoreUnmappedSourceProperties`

So:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
        unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR,
        unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)
public interface CallMapper {

    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "map")
    List<ConnectionDto> map(List<ConnectionEntity> connectionEntities);

    @BeanMapping( ignoreUnmappedSourceProperties={"id"} )
    ConnectionDto map(ConnectionEntity connectionEntity);
}
```

You don't need to specify a list mapping, unless  you need this from the outside.. MapStruct will generate one for your.. If you do need the list from the outside, you possibly don't need the qualifier.. The Generic + List are enough